# Is there a single PHP API to post to multiple sharing sites (Twitter, Reddit, Linkedin, etc)?

Tags: php, twitter, youtube-api, linkedin-api

Is there a single PHP API to post to multiple sharing sites (Twitter, Reddit, Linkedin, YouTube etc), or do I have to use multiple APIs? Or is there an online service that will do this via, say, a REST interface?

Comment: Does Youtube really count as a sharing site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, I know a lot of people use hootsuite to update multiple networks however I didnt see anything about an API on their site. In searching i found two that looked ok and offered APIs. They both update ~40 services however I didn't see reddit or youtube. You can check them out though, maybe you're able to link one account to another like facebook lets you do with twitter. Anyway the sites are:

http://ping.fm

http://hellotxt.com

Answer (score 0):

Ping.fm supports quite a few services and has an API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single API for all services, so to speak, but there are multiple GitHub projects that do this!

- [**Social Share URLs**](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)
- [**Sharer.js**](https://github.com/ellisonleao/sharer.js)

*I personally contribute to both of these projects on GitHub!  Even though there is a "support" button there for contributions for Sharer.js, they go to the project owners -- and I'm only a contributor, not a project owner!*

[image: Social Share URLs Image]